# Missing "i"'s at the start of words during plain paste

Tags: 20.04

I just upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04, now when I try to paste something into the terminal with CTRL-SHIFT-V every "i" at the start of the word is missing.

e.g.

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

becomes

```
sudo apt nstall python3-pip
```

EDIT: I think the error is slightly different: actually every "i" before "n" disappears, rather than "i" at the start of the word. e.g. `ice` doesn't change, but `wine` becomes `wne`.

Comment: What happens when you copy from and paste to the ***same*** terminal?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli If I do it with SHIFT-CTRL-C, SHIFT-CTRL-V the problem also happens